# How do you draw a bimatrix for game theory using Osborne's sgame.sty guide?

Tags: tables, matrices

Martin Osborne has a powerful guide on creating bimatrix for game theory https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/

I am not familiar as to how I can incorporate a .sty file to my latex. I was expecting to use a package instead.

Can anyone teach me how I can use the .sty file so I can gain access to library of commands such as

> \begin{game}{2}{2}
>
> ...
>
> \end{game}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .sty file ***is*** a "package". Since the `sgame` package (which means `sgame.sty` and accompanying documentation) resides at CTAN.org, there is a good chance that your LaTeX installation will automatically know how to download and access it merely by placing `\usepackage{sgame}` in your document preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame}
\begin{document}
\begin{game}{2}{2}
      & $L$     & $M$\\
$T$   & $2,10$  & $2,0$\\
$B$   & $3,0$   & $0,9$
\end{game}
\end{document}
```

[image]